# PL/SQL Select inside Loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL statement that should iterate through a select statement, execute a stored procedure and then select something from a table.

The statement looks like the one below:

```
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (
        select org_id ,name from table2 order by 1
    ) LOOP

        dbms_application_info.set_cl (r.org_id);
        Select prj_id, prj_name 
        INTO l_output
        FROM table1
        WHERE CREATION_DATE>TO_DATE('10/01/2017','DD-MM-YYYY');   
        dbms_sql.return_result(l_output); --error     
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I don't know how to display all the rows returned by the query. Could someone try to help me figure this out? I searched for a solution but without any luck until now..

PS: Table1 is a view that needs to have the stored procedure initiated before the select

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you mean by _display result_ ? Do you want just print values from inner query?

Comment: Yup, that is what I want.. to print the values

Comment: Why is the select query inside the loop? I don't see any column being used in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So maybe use the same construction as in outer query?

```
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (
        select org_id ,name from table2 order by 1
    ) LOOP

        dbms_application_info.set_cl (r.org_id);

        FOR inner_query IN (
          Select prj_id, prj_name 
          FROM table1
          WHERE CREATION_DATE>TO_DATE('10/01/2017','DD-MM-YYYY');   
        ) LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line('prj_id: ' || inner_query.prj_id || ' prj_name:' || inner_query.prj_name);
        END LOOP;  
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**Edit:**
If you want implicitly return cursor from your procedure through `dbms_sql.return_result` you should declare variable as ref_cursor:

```
l_output SYS_REFCURSOR
```

And then open it for your query:

```
 OPEN l_output FOR SELECT ...
```

And finally return with following procedure:

```
 DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(l_output);
```

Comment: I recommend to avoid structures like "Loop in the loop", cause its very resource demanding and often hard to read and maintain.

Comment: I did set the l_output as SYS_REFCURSOR but I have the following error: component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared

Comment: @Ychdziu I don't agree that loop in the loop is very resource demanding, as it always depends on what you want to achieve from. Anyway, OP just wants to print values from the query based on the element of the collection, so beyond loop in the loop where he can use an aggregate function which can be harder to read than this.

Comment: @rosuandreimihai what's your database version? RETURN_RESULT is available from 12c onward

Comment: @mkuligowski , in this particular case - yes,it could not be demanding, but overall, for freshly baked programmers, our role is to spread "good" code and "good" practice. Often, when using "Loop in the loop", it already gives signal, that the programmer didn't study the data well enough or the overall data model is bad. Often this structure can be easily written in one select statement with correct join conditions.

Comment: @Ychdziu you are wrong, because _dbms_application_info.set_cl (r.org_id);_ procedure set the global context for _table1_ - that's why you are not able to write it as one joined query. Please read OP question properly.

Comment: @mkuligowski how to handle in this case? Our database is 11.2

Comment: @rosuandreimihai just print it as in my answer using _dbms_output.put_line_

Answer (score 2):

Procedure `dbms_sql.return_result` accepts/returns a ref cursor, you need to open the ref cursor before calling this procedure:

```
    DECLARE
      l_output sys_refcursor;    
    BEGIN
      FOR r IN (SELECT org_id,
                       NAME
                  FROM table2
                 ORDER BY 1) LOOP

        dbms_application_info.set_cl(r.org_id);
        OPEN l_output FOR
          SELECT prj_id,
                 prj_name
            FROM table1
           WHERE creation_date > to_date('10/01/2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
        dbms_sql.return_result(l_output);
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: Hi, the error returned is: identifier 'L_OUTPUT' must be declared

Comment: Hi, thank you! But still.. the error that I receive is: component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared

Comment: If you are still getting this error, then I doubt that you do not have access on package 'DBMS_SQL', ask your admin for execute privilege on this package.

Comment: If he wouldn't have access to DBMS_SQL then the error would be: component 'DBMS_SQL' must be declared

Comment: Found out, that dbms_sql.return_result is in DB version 12c and up. In older versions - there are no info about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN
    FOR r IN (select org_id ,name from table2 order by 1)
       LOOP
          dbms_application_info.set_cl (r.org_id);
         for x in (Select prj_id, prj_name
                    FROM table1
                   WHERE CREATION_DATE>TO_DATE('10/01/2017','DD-MM-YYYY'))
            loop   
              dbms_output.put_line('prj_id:  '||x.prj_id ||'  prj_name:  '||x.prj_name );
         end loop;     
    END LOOP;
END;
```